# JavaScript: Appending Content (When target could be absent)

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a JavaScript function for appending content to multiple elements by class.

My function (working) looks like this:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){ 

   var myelements = document.querySelectorAll('.my-elements');

   for (i = 0; i < myelements.length; ++i) {

   myelements[i].innerHTML ='This is an example';

   }

});
```

However what happens when no element with the class `.my-elements` exists? Is it safe to run the function this way when the target may or may not exist?

If not, what would be an appropriate solution.

No jQuery please.

Comment: no problem will occurs with this code

Comment: document.querySelectorAll returns empty array when no elements present. you can use your code as it is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If no element with the class `my-elements` exists then the array returned will be empty, your for loop will terminate doing nothing and no errors will occur.

Answer (score 0):

you can put a `IF` condition before the `for` loop

```
if(myelements.length > 0)
```

This would ensure that your for loop gets executed only when elements with class `.my-elements` exist.